# I need two different column values based on different condition from same table

Tags: mysql, sql

Heading

i want to get result sum of  1st record of each 'tank id' per day wise and sum of 'receipt' per day wise and whole data will be limited for particular month

```
SELECT
  DATE(t.DATE) AS 'Date',
  SUM(t.in_stock) AS 'Opening Stock',
  SUM(receipt) AS 'Receipt',
  SUM(in_stock + receipt)AS 'Total Stock' 
FROM diesel_tank_details t 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT
      1 
    FROM diesel_tank_details t2 
    WHERE
      DATE(t2.DATE) = DATE(t.DATE) 
      AND t2.tank_id = t.tank_id 
      AND t2.dt_id < t.dt_id
  )
  AND YEAR(DATE) = 2019 
  AND MONTH(DATE) = 7 
GROUP BY DATE(DATE)
```

```
Tank_ID    In_Stock  Receipt  Date
1          1000      1000     2019-07-10 00:28:33
2          2000      2000     2019-07-10 00:28:40
3          3000      3000     2019-07-10 00:28:47
1          300       0        2019-07-10 00:32:40
1          250       0        2019-07-15 15:15:06
3          2500      0        2019-07-15 15:15:37
2          1800      0        2019-07-15 15:35:49
3          2200      0        2019-07-15 16:13:17
1          500       250      2019-07-15 16:13:51
2          2000      200      2019-07-15 16:13:57
3          3000      800      2019-07-15 16:14:03
```

## i need this Output from above table

```
Date        Opening Stock     Receipt    Total Stock
2019-07-10  6000              6000       12000
2019-07-15  4550              1250       4550
```

Comment: Please format the question..

Comment: What is `DT_ID `?

Comment: Why is opening stock for date `2019-07-15` is `4550` and not `12250` ( sum of all `IN_STOCK`)?

Comment: DT_ID=transaction id,generate Day wise report

Comment: day wise sum of 1st transaction  per tank

Comment: There's a lot of missing things that the OP must fill.

Comment: actually i am getting 0 sum of all receipt on 2019-07-15

Comment: can anyone tell me how to get sum of instock in different condition and sum of receipt in different condition based on date from same table

Comment: Why is the sum=4550 and not 5800 for 2019-07-15?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want different conditions for stock and receipt you must sum different rows for each case:

```
select s.day, s.`Opening Stock`, r.Receipt,
  (s.`Opening Stock` + s.Receipt) `Total Stock`
from (
  select g.day, sum(t.in_stock) `Opening Stock`, sum(t.receipt) receipt
  from diesel_tank_details t inner join (
    select date(date) day, tank_id, min(date) mindate
    from diesel_tank_details
    where in_stock <> 0
    group by date(date), tank_id
  ) g on g.tank_id = t.tank_id and g.mindate = t.date   
  group by g.day
) s inner join (
  select g.day, sum(t.receipt) Receipt
  from diesel_tank_details t inner join (
    select date(date) day, tank_id, min(date) mindate
    from diesel_tank_details
    where receipt <> 0
    group by date(date), tank_id
  ) g on g.tank_id = t.tank_id and g.mindate = t.date   
  group by g.day  
) r on r.day = s.day
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vbCeR9WPL5FTCQ2VwMLFcj/1).
Results:

```
| day        | Opening Stock | Receipt | Total Stock |
| ---------- | ------------- | ------- | ----------- |
| 2019-07-10 | 6000          | 6000    | 12000       |
| 2019-07-15 | 4550          | 1250    | 4550        |
```

Answer (score 0):

**Query**:

```
SELECT DATE(t.Date) as 'Date',
       SUM(t.In_Stock) as 'Opening Stock',
       SUM(t.Receipt) as 'Receipt',
       SUM(t.In_Stock + t.Receipt) as 'Total Stock'

FROM   diesel_tank_details t

WHERE  AND YEAR(t.Date) = 2019
       AND MONTH(t.Date) = 7

GROUP BY DATE(t.Date)
```

Just include your additional filter. I don't know what `DT_ID` does so i just removed it. but basically you just wanted to group it by day.

Comment: no, sir i need 'opening stock'= sum of 1st data 'In_stock' of every tank based on tank id

Comment: Date                Opening Stock      Receipt         Total Stock
2019-07-10      6000                     6000              12000
2019-07-15      4550                     0                     4550

Comment: Dude your numbers doesn't match. i am trying to understand your point but i'm having a hard time with your explanation